# How to add right sliding pane without extending width of page?

Tags: html, css

I'm not quite sure how to title this better, so edits are welcome.

Basically I wanted to animate a right side sliding-in panel in a page over a fixed div panel.

My jQuery ajax does what its supposed to do to animate it. However, I just noticed that after adding the `sliding-panel` there was a horizontal scroll bar. Indeed it was my `sliding-panel`.

How can I "hide" it without extending or allowing the user to scroll horizontally and find the empty panel?

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="left-pane">
    <div id="left-conent"></div>
</div>
<div class="sliding-panel" style="position: absolute;z-index: 1000;width: 400px;height: 90%;background-color: whitesmoke;right: -400px;">
    <div id="pane-content-edit" class="pane-content">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="right-pane" class="right-pane">
    <div id="pane-content" class="pane-content">
       ...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.right-pane{
    width:400px;
    height:90%;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    z-index: 999;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
```

Comment: have you tried `overflow:hidden;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply to body if no overflow is needed. Read about [overflow](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/)

```css
.right-pane {
  width: 400px;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  z-index: 999;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-pane">
  <div id="left-conent"></div>
</div>
<div class="sliding-panel" style="position: absolute;z-index: 1000;width: 400px;height: 90%;background-color: whitesmoke;right: -400px;">
  <div id="pane-content-edit" class="pane-content">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="right-pane" class="right-pane">
  <div id="pane-content" class="pane-content">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked! I'd ask for an explanation why it only took that single line. But I'll also read up :D Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As a possible solution - use `overflow-x: hidden` on the `body` tag. But in case the user doesn't have a screen big enough to show the whole, horizontal scrollbar will not appear. Hence the usability of your website will be significantly reduced.

I can suggest you to have a look at this css library in order to achieve the effect of sliding panel - https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/. Then you just need to care about hiding your panel with `display: none` and when you need to show it - add `bounceInRight` class to it.